# Ubuntu wrongly shows low disk space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, virtualbox, virtualization

I installed Ubuntu 14.0 on virtual box. Initially I had allocated 10 GB for the .vdi. I increased it to 25 GB. When I check the size in the settings in virtual box, its showing correctly as 25GB. See below:

[image]

But I am frequently getting error warnings on Ubuntu for Low Disk Space.

I checked in System Monitor > File Systems and see that its not picking up allocated disk space and showing only the old 6.2 GB. See below :

[image]

What should I do to solve this? Please help.

Comment: http://www.superuser.com/

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem...
Used the following to solve the problem:

`vboxmanage modifyhd "/path/to/virtualdrive.vdi" --resize <NewSize>`

open the virtual machine and resize the partition (easily done using gparted). The drive was resized to 100G

Then:

```
# df -h /home/

Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   24G   22G  1.1G  96% /

# lvextend -L +100G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root

Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/root changed from 24.00 GiB (6145 
extents) to 124.00 GiB (31745 extents).

Logical volume ubuntu-vg/root successfully resized.

# resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 

The filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root is now 32506880 (4k) 
blocks long.

# df -h

Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        798M  1.4M  797M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  122G   22G   96G  19% /
```

Answer (score 1):

`df -h` or your GUI system monitor app shows the actual FS characteristics, not the Volume size.

You should first check `/dev/sda` device, then ensure you can update `/dev/sda1` volume size (`fdisk` or other software could be used for this purpose). And after that you should increase FS size using `resize2fs` utils.

Then you'll be able to use whole disk.

Answer (score 0):

U should try "df -h" in terminal and see the big partitions and it's phat. After you use the "du -csh /phat/bing/" to see what file is so big and process it.

Comment: The new size is not taking effect on the vdi. Its still showing only 6GB of total space.